# Coefficient of $x^9$ in $(1+x)\cdot (1+x^2)\cdot (1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^9)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The Coefficient of $x^9$ in $(1+x)\cdot (1+x^2)\cdot (1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^9)$ is

**My Try** We Know that Coefficient  of $x^9$ occur (which is $ = 1$) when we

multiply $x^0\cdot x^9$ and $x^1\cdot x^8$ and $x^2\cdot x^7$ and $x^3\cdot x^6$ and $x^4\cdot x^5$

Now I did not understand How can I calculate it bcz answer given as $ = 8$

Help me, Thanks

Comment: It could also be $x \cdot x ^2 \cdot x^6$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same as the number of ways to express $9$ as the sum of distinct positive integers $\le 9$.

$9 = 9 = 8+1 = 7+2 = 6+3 = 6+2+1 = 5+4 = 5+3+1 = 4+3+2$

So there are eight ways.

Comment: Combinatorics and expanding polynomials (+1).

Comment: But expansion of polynomial is very lengthy.

Comment: @juantheron He just did it without expanding the polynomial.

Comment: By the way, due to one of Euler's theorems, we have that it's the same as the number of ways to express $9$ as the sum of _odd_ positive integers. And, indeed, \begin{align}9&=7+1+1=5+3+1=5+1+1+1+1=3+3+3\\&=3+3+1+1+1=3+1+1+1+1+1+1\\&=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,\end{align}also eight ways.

Comment: Thanks  columbus8myhw got it.